# How the pause Android Intent Service?

Tags: android, android-service

}

Everything works, but when press pause and then tried to resume, still I can upload images but I cant send to broadcast message to activity.

Comment: What do you mean "tried to modify open source code"? Did you write a new ROM just to pause a service?!

Answer (score 0):

Services, by default, are not in their own Thread. So pausing the service is as simple as calling `Thread.sleep()`. However, assuming you are running a Thread in your Service, which I would do since you are uploading images, I would have a a flag in the while loop of the Thread's run method. This flag would be the `IsServicePaused` boolean that would pause or break out of the running loop.

Comment: I already use a flag in my loop. But I tried to resume, still I can upload images but I cannot send broadcastintent to inform activity(I dont know why(. If you want, I can explain in coedes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the OP means what he says, and is using IntentService class, which *does* run in its own Thread. If so, one way to pause the work the Service is doing is to send it an Intent which directs it to pause. You then have to modify the code that does the work to check regularly to see if a pause has been issued.

However, I'm a bit puzzled. Why do you want to pause the Service? It's running in the background, asynchronously from what the user is doing in the Activity. What's the use case 
for the user having to pause the display of images? One way to handle this would be to fire off the image download from the Activity, then allow the user to do other work either in your app or some other app. When all the images are downloaded, post a notification and attach a PendingIntent to it. When the user clicks the notification, control passes back to your app. I think this is the best pattern for implementing an app lifecycle with asynchronous work.

Comment: I need pause button because user maybe give up uploading this images or doesnt want to use his internet connection for upload.

Answer (score 0):

Call Looper.loop() and have it handle a message.

Comment: where should I call this method, also I deleted this line "stopSelf(msg.arg1); in "IntenService " class in method "public void   handleMessage(Message msg)".